# When was the last prime number discovered?

Tags: prime-numbers, math-history

By last, I mean the most recently discovered prime number.
What was the length of time between the discovery of the last two prime numbers?

Comment: Apparently they keep finding new ones @ [PrimeGrid](http://www.primegrid.com/).

Comment: This question may be impossible to reasonably answer depending on what you mean by "discovered," but see http://primes.utm.edu/largest.html for a start.

Comment: @J.M. You seem to be two steps behind the times... (-;

Comment: The [most recent primes](http://primes.utm.edu/primes/status.php) on the database all date from the last 72 hours, so I would say that these days the "length of time between discovery" is pretty short.

Comment: (corrected) According to the [Prime Database's](http://primes.utm.edu/primes/) list of [100 largest known primes](http://primes.utm.edu/primes/search.php?Number=100), the largest known prime was discovered in 2008, has 12978189 digits, and equals $2^{43112609}-1$.

Comment: @Arturo: not to mention primes being generated by implementations of cryptographic algorithms across the globe, some of which may be "new" by sheer luck...

Comment: As stated, the question is too localized and I have voted to close as such. If you change the question to something like: "Is there a resource which maintains the 'latest' prime?", then consider my close voted withdrawn.

Comment: I just discovered 876797689865765453447867987711 two seconds ago.

Comment: Personally I think that the question may not be a good one, but for people at a certain level of mathematical knowledge it is the one they ask, and the comments and answers open up a mathematical world which may be interesting and inspiring for them. The site advertises itself as catering for all mathematical abilities. I agree that a reformulated question might help, but I think there may be many high-school students who aren't aware just how quickly primes are being identified, and that fact is not, so far as I know, in any of the accessible literature. I hope a version of this is reopened.

Comment: OK, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that you too can discover a new prime number.  Go to http://www.wolframalpha.com/ and enter "what is the next prime number after X" where X is a random string of 30 or so digits.  The result will be a prime number slightly larger than X which, with very high probability, no human eyes have ever seen before.

Answer (score 6):

See the page *[The Largest Known Primes--A Summary](http://primes.utm.edu/largest.html)* by Chris K. Caldwell

> (A historic Prime Page resource since 1994!)
>
> Last modified: 16:20:41 Monday August 29 2011 UTC.

In particular [this subpage](http://primes.utm.edu/largest.html#biggest) and [this one](http://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=3).

Comment: The Yves Gallot's program Proth.exe based on the [Proth's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth%27s_theorem) is available from [here](http://primes.utm.edu/programs/gallot/)

Answer (score 4):

Apart from very large "special" primes, it is also possible to make/construct large "certified" primes, using the Pocklington-Lehmer criterion. That is, although one must "search" ("randomly") for primes readily certifiable, once they are found one can "attach" to them a small amount of data that anyone interested could use to verify their primality (via Pocklington-Lehmer, for example). In particular, although the search is obviously probabilistic, the certification is not.